# Why does my bash output 0 0 instead of the read string

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Im trying to split this string into a first and last name and the output becomes 0 0 whenever i'm trying to split the string.

I am expecting the outcome to become print out the first and last name in seperate variables instead it produces 0 0

```
read fullName
IFS=' '
read -ra splitName<<<"$fullName"
let firstName="${splitName[0]}"
let lastName="${splitName[1]}"
echo $firstName
echo $lastName
```

Comment: There's no need to use an array. Just use `read firstName lastName <<<"$fileName"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` is for evaluating arithmetic expressions. Since the first and last names are not numeric, they're treated as `0`. Just use ordinary variable assignments.

```
read -r fullName
IFS=' ' read -ra splitName <<<"$fullName"
firstName="${splitName[0]}"
lastName="${splitName[1]}"
echo "$firstName"
echo "$lastName"
```

Comment: wow what a simple mistake thank you

Comment: I'd also recommend making `IFS=' '` a prefix to the `read` command so it only affects that (leaving IFS set to a nonstandard value can have weird effects), and also double-quoting all variable references (e.g. `echo "$firstName"`).

Comment: What about `${splitName[3]}`?  Consider `lastName="${splitName[*]:1}"` or even simplier, as your 1st comment: `read -r firstName lastName <<<"$fullName"`